# 404/405 Errors With Cross Domain Javascript access to WCF Self hosted Service

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

I have a very simple webHttpBinding WCF Service running which accepts POST. If I send a GET - the response is

> Status 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> Response headers  Allow: POST  Content-Length: 0  Server:

So the service is receiving the GET and responding it only accepts POST which is correct. If I then Send a POST I get this:

> Status 404 Not Found
>
> Response headers  Content-Length: 0  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

The WCF Services configuration is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>    
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RaptorHTTPService.RaptorHTTPService">
        <endpoint address="RaptorHTTPService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" contract="RaptorHTTPService.IRaptorHTTPService" name="WebEndpoint">         
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://ccs-labs.com:8008/RaptorHTTPService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" allowCookies="true"  />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>      
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>         
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The interface looks like this:

```
namespace RaptorHTTPService
{

    [ServiceContract]    
    public interface IRaptorHTTPService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SendData/{srcUrl}", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]        
        void GetData(string srcUrl);
    }      
}
```

I am using Advanced Rest Client on Chrome for testing I am sending the payload to: `http://ccs-labs.com:8008/RaptorHTTPService/Service1/SendData/` and the payload is `http://www.google.co.uk`

**Can anyone see where this is going wrong and explain the problem to me?**

Comment: I think your URL should be "http://ccs-labs.com:8008/RaptorHTTPService/Service1/RaptorHTTPService/SendData"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing it via `http://ccs-labs.com:8008/RaptorHTTPService/Service1/SendData/` it appears that using `http://ccs-labs.com:8008/RaptorHTTPService/Service1/mex` does work.

**Any ideas why?**